# Use rollapply with xts object and an anonymous defined function

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to create a rolling computation using rollapply on a window that slides down the columns of an xts data frame. For example, suppose I define an xts object:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
              B = c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))
dfxts <- xts(df1, order.by = as.Date(c(30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38)))
```

This gives the xts function:

```
           A  B
1970-01-31 1  3
1970-02-01 2  4
1970-02-02 3  5
1970-02-03 4  6
1970-02-04 5  7
1970-02-05 6  8
1970-02-06 7  9
1970-02-07 8 10
1970-02-08 9 11
```

As I understand the width parameter, it defines the length of a sliding window where some operation takes place, e.g., a mean operation (although I am not clear about ‘width').

Say I wanted to create a rolling operation on a window of width 3 where I add the 2nd and 3rd elements of the window at each position. At each position of the window I want to add x(2) + x(3). I would get:

```
           A  B
1970-01-31 NA NA
1970-02-01 NA NA
1970-02-02 5  9
1970-02-03 7  11
1970-02-04 9  13
1970-02-05 11 15
1970-02-06 13 17
1970-02-07 15 19
1970-02-08 17 21
```

I try to implement this with:

```
 rollapply(dfxts, width = 3, FUN=function(x) x(2)+x(3), align = "right")
```

and I get the error:

> "Error during wrapup: could not find function “x"

I think I misunderstand how to use rollapply, how to implement an anonymous function, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can apply the `rollapply` to the entire dataframe. You can apply it to every column separately with `lapply` and since you want `sum` of second and third element you can reduce the `width` as 2 instead

```
library(zoo)
lapply(dfxts, function(x) rollapply(x, width = 2, FUN=sum))


#$A
#            A
#1970-01-31 NA
#1970-02-01  3
#1970-02-02  5
#1970-02-03  7
#1970-02-04  9
#1970-02-05 11
#1970-02-06 13
#1970-02-07 15
#1970-02-08 17

#$B
#            B
#1970-01-31 NA
#1970-02-01  7
#1970-02-02  9
#1970-02-03 11
#1970-02-04 13
#1970-02-05 15
#1970-02-06 17
#1970-02-07 19
#1970-02-08 21
```

---

If for some reason you have to keep `width` as 3 only and can't change it then we can do

```
lapply(dfxts, function(x) rollapply(x, width = 3, FUN=function(y) sum(y[2],y[3])))
```

which will give the same output except first two values would be `NA` instead of one.

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments the actual function to be applied is more complicated then the one which is presented and it would require using custom functions rather than in-built functions we can use `coredata` to get the actual data and then apply our function accordingly.

So in the given example, we could do

```
rollapply(dfxts, width = 3, FUN=function(x) coredata(x[2]) +  coredata(x[3]))
```

However, for a more general approach , we can call `coredata` only once and then use them the way we want. so if we want to apply operation `5*x(5) - 8*x(7) + x(15)`, we could do

```
rollapply(dfxts, width = 15, FUN=function(x) {
          vals <- coredata(x)
          5*vals[5] - 8*vals[7] + vals[15]
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Good solutions to the problem I presented, but I picked a poor example of x(2) + x(3). My real problem is a more complicated operation on the values inside the width. For example, I might have a width of, say, 15 and my real function might look more like 5*x(5) - 8*x(7) + x(15). So, I need to call my own defined function, rather than use a built-in function like ‘sum.'

Comment: @Ernie I have updated my answer. See if it helps Thanks :)

Comment: Perfect! Not converting using ‘coredata’ was my main mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight change to your rollapply (`sum(x[2],x[3])` instead of `x(2)+x(3)`) and it works:

```
rollapply(dfxts, width = 3, FUN=function(x) sum(x[2],x[3]), align = "right")
```

Here is the output I get:

```
#            A  B
#1970-01-31 NA NA
#1970-02-01 NA NA
#1970-02-02  5  9
#1970-02-03  7 11
#1970-02-04  9 13
#1970-02-05 11 15
#1970-02-06 13 17
#1970-02-07 15 19
#1970-02-08 17 21
```

Hope it helps.